# Why does a different page load up in the interval of loading up the page I want?

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium-webdriver, automation

I have over hundred test scripts in Selenium C# within Visual Studio 2017.  These scripts are distributed over numerous .class files to allocate names for the different functionalities/web pages of the site.  BTW this is a telemetry software so it uses signalR functionality too....just giving you some background here.  Now my problem is whenever I run a script lets say a test method in A.class which represents one web page, before it loads it will go to another page(ALWAYS the same page from B.class).  It doesn't matter if I run test scripts(test methods) from C.class, D.class, it will always get interrupted by the landing page from within the B.class.  This is weird behavior and funny enough it has only started happening since I have been putting in lines of javascript.  So please can someone suggest a solution?

To be honest I haven't tried anything apart from doing research on the net and the closest thing I got was an article, pls see link

https://blog.codeship.com/get-selenium-to-wait-for-page-load/

So I am guessing I need some code to wait for page to load so that it disturbs the interrupted landing web page?

Please see one of my scripts and pls critique all you want:

```cs
[TestMethod]
[TestCategory("OrgMgt")]
public void EditOrgDetails()
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
    IJavaScriptExecutor executor = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
    executor.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click()", userSetRepo.userIcon);
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
    objCommon.SendKeysAndClickTab(_regRep.organizationOption, "M-Powered Automation", driver);
    ChooseOrgMgt();
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
    driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[@class='Select-arrow-zone']")).Click();
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
    IWebElement dd = driver.FindElement(By.Id("vt-org-details-default-zoom"));
    dd.Click();
    _regRep.ClearAndSetText(dd, "17");
    _regRep.ClearAndSetText(_orgRep.supportPhoneNo, "6666666666");
    _regRep.ClearAndSetText(_regRep.Lattitude, "567.876768");
    _regRep.ClearAndSetText(_regRep.Longitude, "3434.56767");
    _regRep.DistanceInput.SendKeys("Kilometers");
    _regRep.DistanceInput.SendKeys(Keys.Tab);

    _regRep.VehicleType.SendKeys("Car");
    _regRep.VehicleType.SendKeys(Keys.Tab);

    _regRep.TimeZone.SendKeys("Coordinated Universal Time-11");
    _regRep.TimeZone.SendKeys(Keys.Tab);
    _regRep.SearchAddress.SendKeys("room");
    _regRep.SearchAddressOption.Click();
    objCommon.ScrollInToView(_regRep.btnUpdateOrganization);
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
    Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
    builder.MoveToElement(_regRep.btnUpdateOrganization).Click().Build().Perform();
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
    bool isDisplayed = false;
    try
    {
        isDisplayed = _regRep.OrganizationUpdatedMsg.Displayed;
    }
    catch
    {
        isDisplayed = false;
    }

    if (!isDisplayed)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Success Message is NOT displayed. Please check if record is added");
        Assert.IsTrue(isDisplayed);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Success Message is displayed.Record is successfuly added");
    }
}
```

I need it to not be interrupted and go straight to the page I want.